# In nodejs, NaN is returned when a post request of api using bodyparser is made

Tags: node.js, api, npm, body-parser

Version
nodejs v16.15.0
npm 8.10.0

I created an api in nodejs as follows

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const sayHi = (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hi!");
};

app.get("/", sayHi);

app.post("/add", (req, res) => {
  const { a, b } = req.body;
  res.send(`The sum is: ${a + b}`);
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port 5000.`);
});
```

The get request became a response.
NaN is returned in response to post requests.

```
{
    "a": 5,
    "b": 10
}
```

```
The sum is: NaN
```

Comment: how you are calling this API?

Comment: calling as postman.

Comment: What's your `content-type` in a request? Add `console.log(req.headers['content-type']);` before `const { a, b }`. What it will be?

Comment: It looks like you are waiting for a `Content-Type` header as `application/json` when you did `bodyParser.json()` but send a body another way.